# Bind iList to DataGridView, DGV not updating

Tags: c#, datagridview, ilist

I have a simple test class:

```
public partial class TEST_CLASS
{
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public int PORT { get; set; }
}

iList<TEST_CLASS> MY_CLASS = new List<TEST_CLASS>();
```

And I have the following code to bind the class to DGV:

```
        TEST_CLASS n = new TEST_CLASS();
        MY_CLASS.Add(n);


        grid_nodes.DataSource = MY_CLASS;

        Thread t = new Thread(set1);
        t.Start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(set2);
        t2.Start();
```

And The threads that update the class to random values for testing purposes:

```
    public void set1()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            MY_CLASS[0].IP = r.Next(999900);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public void set2()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            MY_CLASS[0].PORT = r.Next(999900);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that DGV is not getting updated right. I only see the updates each time a click in a cell.

I'm going to have thousands of rows and separate threads updating the MY_CLASS and I need the changes to be displayed 'live' on the DGV.

As far as I understand I need to call DGV.Update() each time I update my class? What would be the best way of doing this, since I'm going to have thousands of threads updating the class constantly? Thanks!

Comment: `thousands of threads updating the class constantly` is troubling, are you certain that the class is thread safe?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Not sure what you mean, I guess probably not. Just a simple class with variables in a List. Can you point me where I can learn more about this? Also, all I'm looking for is a simple code example that does what I'm trying to accomplish, but I can't seem to find anything. Is this really that 'rear' of a task to accomplish? Thanks

Comment: Some information on [Thread Synchronization in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx), and [Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx) in C#.

Comment: If you use BindingList instead of List, and make your TEST_CLASS implement INotifyPropertyChanged, then the grid will update itself. However you will need to ensure that only happens on the UI thread by some form of marshalling (like SynchronizationContext or grid.Invoke()).

Comment: @IgbyLargeman Thanks a lot! INotifyPropertyChanged was exactly what I needed, works perfectly now!!

Comment: @user1015551: I've made my comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) instead of List, and make your TEST_CLASS implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx), then the grid will update itself. However you will need to ensure that only happens on the UI thread by some form of marshalling (like [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx31754f.aspx) or grid.[Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)()).

Answer (score 2):

ok, so I simply added the following code in a timer and make it trigger under some conditions, which works great:

```
            grid.DataSource = null;
            grid.DataSource = MY_LIST;
            grid.Invalidate();
```

Comment: You are going to get cross thread exceptions if you do this without any synchronization. Only the UI thread should be updating the grid. Make sure you do this with grid.Invoke().